# $| (x,1)-(x,x^2) | + \bigg|(x,x^2)-\bigg(0,-\frac{1}{8}-\epsilon \bigg)\bigg|$ is increasing

Tags: geometry

From $\sqrt{ x^2+(y-\frac{1}{4})^2 } = y+\frac{1}{4}
$, we have a parabola $y=x^2$. Then we define $$f(x) = |
(x,1)-(x,x^2) | + \bigg|(x,x^2)-\bigg(0,-\frac{1}{8}-\epsilon \bigg)\bigg|$$ for some
small $\varepsilon
>0$. Prove that $f(x)$ is increasing for $0<x<\frac{1}{2}$ :

$f(x) =1-x^2+ \sqrt{x^2+ (x^2+ \frac{1}{8}+\varepsilon )^2}$ so that $$
 f'(x) =x \frac{1+2 T -2\sqrt{x^2+ T^2} }{\sqrt{x^2+ T^2}} >0,\ T=
 x^2+ \frac{1}{8}+\varepsilon $$

Maybe, **is there any other proof** ?

Comment: Why is f'(x) positive for every x?